# how to write a firewall auto logon app in c#

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, httpwebrequest

During my working day I need to authenticate through about 90,000 firewalls on our intranet and also from home via a vpn, I was wondering how easy it would be to automate the process. I want to use c#, and have came up with something like this (which doesn't work).

```
...
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Proxy.Credentials = request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someusername", "somepass");
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Timeout = 10 * 1000;
var response = request.GetResponse();
...
```

This code appears to work OK, I get the right response details anyway, but if I then try and access the web pages in my web browser, I'm still asked to logon.

How do I persist the connection/authentication detail? cookies? Or am I doing it completely wrong this way?

ps. I know I can get apps to do this, but I wanted to do this myself.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot authenticate one application from within another one.  That would be a gargantuan security issue. Only exception I can come up with is usage of some sort of certificate but it needs to be supported on both ends (think of SSH as an example).

Comment: Do you have access to the source of the target pages?

Comment: You can't do it from within another app, true enough, but (depending on assorted factors) you may be able to do it by writing an app which, rather than accessing the web itself to authenticate, automates your web browser to do it.  Then the authentication'll be left in your web browser when you come to use it.

(If the web browser in question is IE, this may be useful as a starting point:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9683/Automating-Internet-Explorer
)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the authentication mechanism that is used in your firewall web interface.
The important thing is that you have to login and create a session on the firewall web interface which you can use after that in your browser. You can try to figure out your session key (POST, GET, Cookie etc.) and try to "transfer" it from your c# web response to your browser. But as Alex already indicate if that works you should think about using another firewall ;)

To get such a nice Admin-Helper-Tool I would try to use a WebBrowser control inside your app and use this "framed browser" to auto-login to your firewall web app.
Something like that should also work for a firewall web interface: 
http://www.codegain.com/articles/csharp/utilities/automating-facebook-login-using-webbrowser-control-in-csharp.aspx